# Python fetching <title>

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to fetch the title of a webpage which I open using urllib2. What is the best way to do this, to parse the html and find what I need (for now only the -tag but might need more in the future).

Is there a good parsing lib for this purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes I would recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

If you're getting the title it's simply:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
myTitle = soup.html.head.title
```

or

```
myTitle = soup('title')
```

Taken from [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

It's very robust and will parse the html no matter how messy it is.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
title = soup.html.head.title
print title.contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("...").read()
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.title.string
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you guys importing a whole extra library for one task.  No regular expressions?  wasn't the request for urllib not bs4 or mech which are third party?  to do with standard libraries parse the html and match the string then split the `'>'` `'<'` with re or whateves.

```
N=(len(html))
for a in html(N):
    if '<title>' in a:
        Title=(str(a))
```

thats python 2 I think, you can strip it

Comment: Love the answer. That was my question exactly, why would you add a whole other dependency for ONE invocation. Thank you for your wisdom :)

Comment: this only works if the `html` is properly formatted