# Getting url title with python

Tags: python, url, title

I'd like to ask is there any way to get url title with python ? And if yes, simple code or just any idea how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660302/python-fetching-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using BeautifulSoup and urllib2.urlopen you could try:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#fetch html
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#parse with BeautifulSoup
BS = BeautifulSoup(source)

#search for title element, print element.text
print BS.find('title').text
```